# How do I restore S3 object from Glacier using tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have different types of file on S3 bucket. Assigned tag(key-value pair) to each file to easily identify.

Example: key is type and value is sunset

- type=sunset
- project=travel
- classification=nature

I am regularly archiving all these files on the Glacier.

My question: How can I restore objects from Glacier using a specific tag (key-pair)?

I want to restore all files which have `type=sunset`.

Is any CLI available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible.

Not only does the [`restore_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.restore_object) *NOT* support tags, but there does not appear to be *any* Amazon S3 API call that can retrieve or list objects by tag. Even [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) does not provide a list of tags.

It appears that the only way to retrieve the Tags on an object is to use [`get_object_tagging()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object_tagging), but that command requires a **specific object** to be referenced.

Thus, it seems that Tags are a good way to provide additional information about an object, but cannot be used to *locate* an object.

You will likely need to keep your own database of information if you wish to locate objects via additional data normally stored in tags.

Comment: [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/batch-ops.html) can restore a bulk quantity of objects from Glacier, but it needs an input manifest file of objects to restore. So, this is no help either.